# Kernel of powers of Frobenius on supersingular elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, group-schemes

I am trying to understand some things related to elliptic curves and finite flat group schemes but I am a little bit confused.

Let $A$ be a supersingular elliptic curve over an algebraically closed field $K$ of characteristic $p$.
Let $F: A \rightarrow A^{(p)}$ be the Frobenius isogeny. Then $\ker F$ is as a finite flat group scheme over $K$ isomorphic to $\alpha_p$, the kernel of the Frobenius on $\mathbb{G}_a$.

Now lets look at $F^2: A \rightarrow A^{(p^2)}$.

> Is $\ker F^2: A \rightarrow A^{(p^2)}$ isomorphic (as a $K$-group scheme)  to any one of the following group schemes:
>
> $\ker F^2:\mathbb{G}_a \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_a$
>
> $\ker F : W_2 \rightarrow W_2$ where $W_2$ is the group scheme of truncated Witt vectors
>
> $A[p]$
>
> $\alpha_p \oplus \alpha_p$

If $\ker F^2: A \rightarrow A^{(p^2)}$ is not isomorphic to one of them, I have an other question:

> Is $\ker F^2: A \rightarrow A^{(p^2)}$ an extension of $\alpha_p$ over $\alpha_p$ and why not?

And a last one:

> Is $\ker F^2: A \rightarrow A^{(p^2)}$ isomorphic to an other well-known group scheme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kernel of $F^2$ is the same as the kernel of $[p]$, once $A^{(p^2)}$ and $A$ are identified, and is a non-trivial extension of $\alpha_p$ by $\alpha_p$, whose class can be described in terms of the supersingular modular form $B$. See Ulmer, p-descent in characteristic p. Duke Math. J. 62 (1991), 237–265, section 4, especially Prop 4.1

http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077296358

Comment: The old-fashioned way I see this, and Felipe can slap me down if I’m wrong, is that the transcendence-degree-one field of functions on $A$ has only one purely inseparable subfield of each possible degree $p^r$.